# How to plot a regression tree in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, decision-tree

So, first of all, I'm relatively new to Python so I'm not sure how to achieve my task. I was following an online tutorial on how to plot a decision tree using the Iris dataset (for classification). However, I'm trying to plot a single tree from regression.

Here's a snip of the data I'm using: 
[image: Data]

Here's the code I was using:

```
# Import Libraries and Load Data
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/.../Desktop/cars_test.csv") 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
cars = data

# Model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10)

# Train
model.fit(cars.data, cars.target)

# Extract single tree for analysis
estimator = model.estimators_[5]
```

However, I'm getting an error that I'm not sure how to fix... The error I'm getting is:

> ```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-27-37164305d7fe> in <module>()
>      10 
>      11 # Train
> ---> 12 model.fit(cars.data, cars.target)
>      13 
>      14 # Extract single tree for analysis
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
> __getattr__(self, name)    4370             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):    4371   
> return self[name]
> -> 4372             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)    4373     4374     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
>
> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'
> ```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt the code to deal with your own data (note that the DataFrame you loaded doesn't have attributes for `target` or `data`). This means extracting the matrix of input data (`X`) and response variable (`y`) from your original dataset. I'm making a few assumptions here, but you can adapt accordingly.

```
# Import Libraries and Load Data
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/.../Desktop/cars_test.csv") 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
cars = data

# Model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10)

X = cars.loc[:, cars.columns != 'th_km_per_year'].values
y = cars['th_km_per_year'].values

# Train
model.fit(X, y)

# Extract single tree for analysis
estimator = model.estimators_[5]
```